# Next.js with i18n error : Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "" Client: "fr"

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

We get this error on load.

Application first loads at URL `http://localhost:3000/` then when we switch to ex: french we get `http://localhost:3000/fr` but when we switch languages again to ex: deutsch we get `http://localhost:3000/de/fr` and so on. The new chosen language path inserts between the first chosen language and the root URL.

Also if we go directly to ex: `http://localhost:3000/fr` we land on the correct page with correct language.

```js
//i18n.js
const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next').default;

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  otherLanguages: ['fr', 'de', 'nl', 'it', 'pt', 'es'],
  localeSubpaths: {
    en: 'en',
    fr: 'fr',
    de: 'de',
    nl: 'nl',
    it: 'it',
    es: 'es',
    pt: 'pt',
  },
});
```

```js
//next.config.js

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function (defaultPathMap, { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
    };
  },
  env: {
    GLOBAL_URL: isProd ? 'https://siteurl' : 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
  assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://siteurl' : '',
};
```

```js
// languageDropdown.js
class LanguageDropdown extends Component {
  render() {
    const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
      console.log(lng);
    };
    return (
      <MenuNetwork>
        <ListMenu>
          <ListItemMenu>
            <CurrentLanguage>{i18n.language}</CurrentLanguage>
            <HoverChevron>
              <CustomizeChevronDown size="25" />
            </HoverChevron>
            <SubListMenu>
              <SubListMenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>
                <button>English</button>
              </SubListMenuItem>
              <SubListMenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('fr')}>
                <button>Français</button>
              </SubListMenuItem>
              <SubListMenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('de')}>
                <button>Deutsch</button>
              </SubListMenuItem>
              <SubListMenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('nl')}>
                <button>Nederlands</button>
              </SubListMenuItem>
              <SubListMenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('it')}>
                <button>Italiano</button>
              </SubListMenuItem>
              <SubListMenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('pt')}>
                <button>Português</button>
              </SubListMenuItem>
              <SubListMenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('es')}>
                <button>Español</button>
              </SubListMenuItem>
            </SubListMenu>
          </ListItemMenu>
        </ListMenu>
      </MenuNetwork>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when user changes locale, it goes to index, so I put this code at the index, if it's not your case and the user stays at the same page, you can probably find a way to change this a little bit to work for you.
The workaround I found to avoid this is:

```
   let temp = [];

   if( typeof window != 'undefined'){
     temp = window?.location?.href?.split("/");
   }
   if( typeof temp[4] != 'undefined'  && temp[4] != null && temp[4] != ""){
     window.location.href = temp[0] + "//" + temp[2] + "/" + temp[4];
   }
```

NOTE: my locale was stacking at the end, if yours is in the middle, you should change this line:

```
window.location.href = temp[0] + "//" + temp[2] + "/" + temp[4];
```

to:

```
window.location.href = temp[0] + "//" + temp[2] + "/" + temp[3];
```